# Ruby 1.8 BigDecimal

Tags: ruby

I remember the words said by **Matz**: **Ruby 1.8 will be dead soon**. But I have no option. Here, I am using Ruby `1.8.7`. Big Decimal is behaving differently compare to later version of Ruby.

For example:

```
ree-1.8.7-2011.12 :001 > require 'bigdecimal'
 => true 
ree-1.8.7-2011.12 :002 > b=BigDecimal('0.0')
 => #<BigDecimal:9ce7148,'0.0',4(8)> 
ree-1.8.7-2011.12 :003 > b
 => #<BigDecimal:9ce7148,'0.0',4(8)> 
ree-1.8.7-2011.12 :004 > b==0
 => true

ree-1.8.7-2011.12 :005 > [b,b,0,0].uniq
 => [#<BigDecimal:9ce7148,'0.0',4(8)>, #<BigDecimal:9ce7148,'0.0',4(8)>] #Integer 0 is removed
ree-1.8.7-2011.12 :008 > [b,b,0,0].uniq.uniq
 => [#<BigDecimal:9ce7148,'0.0',4(8)>]  #Applying two times uniq gives desired result for given array
```

Is there any patch to fix this issue? Sorry I don't have option to upgrade Ruby. Any help?
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You might try https://github.com/marcandre/backports, which claims to provide "The latest features of Ruby backported to older versions". I didn't see anything in there regarding BigDecimal, at a glance, but who knows what it might be using internally. I've used it before for arrays, it's at least worth a shot.